# Code not working as expected - Not too sure why

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Task: Trying to make a function that returns true if a given array can be strictly increasing by removing no more than 1 element and false if not.
Examples:

> For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
> solution(sequence) = false.

> For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
> solution(sequence) = true.

Given an input array of `sequence: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]` my code returns true instead of false.
My first if statement in the loop should return false but for some reason is not running as expected.

From my understanding - the for loop should iterate through the array. The If statement should compare the index i to the index in front of it - if it is greater than or equal to the index in front, index i should be removed. Then another iteration should occur with the same idea - only this time if another number is needed to be removed we should return false. If not we will finish the loop and return true.

My code : (EDITED TO MAKE SIMPLER)***

---

```
function solution(sequence){
    for(let i=0; i<sequence.length-2; i++){  
              
    if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1]){
        sequence.splice(sequence[i],1);
        for(let j =0; j<sequence.length-2; j++){ 
              if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1]){
                  return false;
              }
        }
    }   
 
  
}
 return true;
}
```

---

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? What have you done so far to investigate the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by removing no more than 1 element

Comment: If you want _strictly_ increasing, I guess you should use `>` (greater than) instead of `>=` (greater than or equal)

Comment: why should ur first example [1,2,3,1] be false when you said strictly increasing when removing no more than 1 item? removing the last 1 will make it strictly increase

Comment: @Pointy Given an input array of sequence: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4] my code returns true instead of false. My first if statement in the loop should return false but for some reason is not running as expected.

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum As in return true only if one element is needed to be removed. If two are needed to be removed in order for the sequence to be increasing then return false

Comment: ah mb I misread the first example sorry

Comment: @JeremyThille I used >= since doubles need to be removed aswell. I.e [1,1,2] would need the extra 1 removed to be true

Comment: You don't really need to modify the array. You can just keep track of how many values you have to skip. If that number is greater than 1, the return value is false.

Comment: This question is currently part of the general coding assessment used by a lot of companies for hiring screens.  Please come up with your own answer to it instead of asking here.

Comment: @DanielBeck  - I am a beginner and this question can be found on codesignal. I am trying to learn?

Comment: @Pointy Thats true, I could also do it that way. However, just for understanding purposes do you know which part of my code currently is not working as intended?

Comment: @DCoderT: You ticked this box before taking that test on CodeSignal: "I will not copy, reproduce, distribute, or publicly display any of the information I come across during this test, including but not limited to the task descriptions copyrighted by CodeSignal."

Comment: @DanielBeck can't do much now as SOF wont let me delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your line 5, you splice with the value of sequence at the index i (sequence[1])

But what you want is to splice at the index i ;)

```js
function solution(sequence) {
    for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length - 2; i++) {

        if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
            console.log("Sequence[i]: " + sequence[1])
            console.log("Index i is: " + i)
            sequence.splice(i, 1); // Here!!!!
            for (let j = 0; j < sequence.length - 2; j++) {
                if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    return true;
}
console.log(solution([1, 3, 5, 4, 5]))
```

So for this array as an example, we hit that the 5 is bigger than the 4, so what you want is to splice the 5 away which is at index 2, but in your code u splice away the number at index 5 because you call `sequence[i]`, thus your array doesn't even change because 5 is larger than the array size and you splice nothing at all